# What effects do dfs.blocksize, file.blocksize, kfs.blocksize and etc have in hadoop mapreduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I check the `job.xml` file of a hadoop (version 0.21.0) mapreduce job, I found there are multiple `blocksize` settings exist:

- `dfs.blocksize` = 134217728 (i.e. 128MB)
- `file.blocksize` = 67108864 (i.e. 64MB)
- `kfs.blocksize` = 67108864
- `s3.blocksize` = 67108864
- `s3native.blocksize` = 67108864
- `ftp.blocksize` = 67108864

I am expecting some answers to explain following related questions:

1. What are the `dfs`, `file`, `kfs`, `s3` and etc mean in this context?
2. What are the differences among them?
3. What effects do they have when running a mapreduce job?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map reduce can work on data stored on different types of storage systems.The settings above are the default block sizes on the storage techniques used. dfs(distributed file system) is what we commonly use in hadoop has default block size 128MB. Other settings are for file(local), kfs(kosmos distributed filesystem), s3(amazon cloud storage) and ftp(files on ftp server).

You may research them further for a better understanding of each and using them with hadoop features.While running the map reduce job,the settings which are for the particular storage technique being used,are identified for block size.
I hope it was helpful.